# how to access and use sqlalchemy methods inside flask sqlalchemy properly

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Guys how to use sqlalchemy along with flask sqlalchemy since both of them are little different e.g

sqlalchemy example

```css
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
ed_user = User(name='ed', fullname='Ed Jones', nickname='edsnickname')
session.add(ed_user)
```

sqlalchemy example

```css
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ed_user = User(name='ed', fullname='Ed Jones', nickname='edsnickname')
db.session.add(ed_user)
```

the question is that how would we bring the methods from "sqlalchemy" and use it alongside in Flask without creating separating them both and making both of them to work together?
Better question would be how to use sqlalchemy inside flask and use all of its methods inside it?

Comment: See [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) excellent tutorial and chapter 4 in particular.

Comment: thanks man for the link, I kind of figured out using below way in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for my question, I experimented and tried and found out that its simple to access methods from sqlalchemy while being in flask-sqlalchemy. Also it turns out that all of the methods are already imported when we import just SQLAlchemy. Consider the below example

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

Now all methods from sqlalchemy can be accessed just by
db.aliased 
#(instead of from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased)

db.func
#(instead of from sqlalchemy import func)

db.exists
#(instead of from sqlalchemy.sql import exists)

db.relationship
#(instead of from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship)

db.ForeignKey
#(instead of from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey)

db.Table
#(instead of from sqlalchemy import Table,)
```

and so on